# Why is my equipment breaking?

Tags: loop-hero

Occasionally the items in one of my equipment slots will disappear, seemingly without notifying me.  I've gone through entire battles with no weapon!

Why does this happen? Is there some way to know that it's coming, or is it completely random?  Is there a way to know when it's happened, other than keeping an eye on my equipment slots at all times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you fighting bandits? They have a very slim chance of destroying your gear.

Comment: I see, the ability is called [Brigand](https://loophero.fandom.com/wiki/Bandit). I guess I'll need to keep an eye on my equipment when fighting bandits.  Thanks!